# Mederma or Contractubex. What is better for still forming normotrophic scars?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery, self-healing-repairing

Mederma and Contractubex have similar composition.

**Mederma**'s ingredients according to [Tabletwise](https://www.tabletwise.com/mederma-gel/composition-ingredients):

- **Allium Cepa Topical (onion)**
- **Allantoin Topical**
- Purified Water Topical
- Xanthan Gum Topical
- Polyethylene Glycol-4 Topical
- Methylparaben Topical
- Sorbic Acid Topical
- Fragrance Topical

*Note: two main active components are highlighted in **bold**.*

---

**Contractubex**'s ingredients according to [Tabletwise](https://www.tabletwise.com/contractubex-gel/composition-ingredients):

- **Extractum Cepae-Cepalin Topical (onion)**
- **Heparin Topical**
- **Allantoin Topical**

---

Both products are made by the same company - **Merz Pharmaceuticals** (Frankfurt, Germany).

These two gels have almost identical **active** components, except for **heparin**. Contractubex contains it, Mederma doesn't.

---

Which of the products better suited for treating normotrophic scars that aren't older than 6 months?